# Trigger created with compilation errors in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning ORACLE and haven't been able to figure out why i am getting compilation errors when trying to create this trigger. Thank you for any help!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_HISTORY 
BEFORE INSERT ON HISTORY
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE name_d varchar2(50), breed_d varchar2(50), area_d varchar2(50)

BEGIN
SELECT NAME INTO name_d FROM ANIMALS A WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID; 
SELECT BREED INTO breed_d FROM ANIMALS A  WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID; 
SELECT AREA INTO area_d FROM STORE S WHERE S.STORE_ID = :NEW.STORE_ID;

IF (:NEW.DONE ='T') 
THEN 
:NEW.MSG = 'Hi , your animal ' || name_d || ' breed: ' || breed_d  || 'is 
at ' || area_d || '.';
ELSE 
UPDATE :NEW.MSG = 'Not finished';
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: There seems to be lot of issues with your trigger.  Show the error messages you are getting. Also, are all columns you have used in the Trigger available in the table?

Comment: Yes they are, It seems if i do not use any variables and just run the IF statement by itself I am still getting an error :/

Comment: Ok.Check my answer and let me know if it compiled and executes correctly during an INSERT operation because I may not know any other issues with your table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few issues with your `Trigger` code syntax.

- we use semicolons `';'` after each expression in declare not comma
  `','`
- Check the proper syntax for IF Condition.
- `THEN UPDATE 
     :NEW.MSG =`

Is not a valid statement. It is simply `:NEW.MSG :=`

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER tr_history
  BEFORE INSERT ON history
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    name_d  VARCHAR2(50);
    breed_d VARCHAR2(50);
    area_d  VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    SELECT name
    INTO   name_d
    FROM   animals A
    WHERE  A.id = :NEW.id;

    SELECT breed
    INTO   breed_d
    FROM   animals A
    WHERE  A.id = :NEW.id;

    SELECT area
    INTO   area_d
    FROM   store S
    WHERE  S.store_id = :NEW.store_id;

    IF :NEW.done = 'T' THEN
      :NEW.msg := 'Hi , your animal '
                  || name_d
                  || ' breed: '
                  || breed_d
                  || 'is      at '
                  || area_d
                  || '.';
    ELSE
      :NEW.msg := 'Not finished';
    END IF;
END;

/
```